# Make a request for The Google Maps Geolocation API

Tags: php, json, geolocation

I would like to make a request for the web service - Google Geolocation API by using PHP 5. I have experience in XML parsing using PHP, but this one is using JSON format for making the request. I have no idea how to make the request! I think to receive the request is similar the XML parsing!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/

Comment: you don't parse json. you `json_decode()` whatever you get, which gives you a native PHP array/object, and you go from there.

Answer (score 7):

try this(result in json format):

```
public function getGeoPosition($address){
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false" . 
        "&address=" . urlencode($address);

    $json = file_get_contents($url);

    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

     if($data['status']=="OK"){
      return $data['results'];
    }

}

print_r(getGeoPosition('chicago,il'));
```

Comment: Any idea why this request will only work part of the time? It times out quite a bit for me, and it takes forever to actually tell me it has timed out.

Comment: You can try the new url:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA
Also see Usage Limits here: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Business account ,as suggested by your link, Google  supply help. If you don't have a business account you would will need to use use [This API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) which provides xml results.
ie

```
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=anywhere&sensor=true
```

or

```
 sensor=false
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to mohamed's answer:

```
function getGeoPosition($address){
    $url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false" .
        "&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&address=" . urlencode($address);

    $json = file_get_contents($url);

    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
     if($data['status']=="OK"){
      return $data['results'];
    }
}
print_r(getGeoPosition('chicago,il'));
```

Note that the request needs to be made over https and needs an API key which is not restricted.