# PHP Google Maps Geolocation Request Failing Half Of The Time

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, request

I retrieved this function for making requests to Google Maps Geolocation API using PHP.

[Make a request for The Google Maps Geolocation API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814609/make-a-request-for-the-google-maps-geolocation-api)

The issue I am having is the request fails around 50% of the time, and it takes forever to actually time out. ( Example: I'll make the request, and it will fail after about 20 seconds. I will refresh the page thus making the request again without changing any information, and it works ) I am trying to write this function into a class, but the service has been far too unreliable.

**The Error:**

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=+chicago+IL): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in filename.php on line 2132
```

*Is there any reason why?*

*Can I force this to timeout sooner?*

**Note:**
**HTACCESS is currently blocking all but my IP, but changing this doesn't seem to help**

```
public function getGeoPosition($address){
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false" . 
        "&address=" . urlencode($address);

    $json = file_get_contents($url);

    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

     if($data['status']=="OK"){
      return $data['results'];
    }

}

print_r(getGeoPosition('chicago,il'));
```

Comment: As far as I know, there's a limit; something like ten queries in a row. I had a similar issue getting LatLng for an address then I just added a pause after every tenth request I guess.

Comment: It's really frustrating because it seems to happen at random entirely. Literally almost every 2nd attempt, and this is completely not usable. Do you know of a way around this, if you have a business account or something?

Comment: If you have a business account, there are other rules.